# Active Admin custom filter for has many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am trying to implement for a custom filter in Active Admin:

The model:

```
Employer < ActiveRecord::Base 
has_many :jobs
has_many :job_applications, through :jobs
```

Now the model:

```
JobApplication < ActiveRecord ::Base 
belongs_to: jobs
```

has a status enumeration regarding the status of some application. There are about 8 different fields. I would like to create a filter in `ActiveAdmin.register Employer do ...` to fetch the number of JobApplciations with a status "employer_accepted".

I have tried using a counter_cache and have read about ransack methods but am struggling to produce something that works. I'm still relatively new to rails so unsure of what to google. If I can give any more information let me know.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to fetch number of JobApplications with a given status `employer_accepted`.

You can do this using a scope.

Define a scope in your model 
`app/models/employer.rb`:

```
scope :accepted, -> { joins(:job_applications).where("job_applications.status = 'employer_accepted'")}
```

Then on the activeadmin page `app/models/employer.rb`:

```
scope :accepted, show_count: false
```